# Strange Windows.Opacity behavior

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a button event that causes smooth opacity and window minimize.

```
private void Button_WindowMinimize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoubleAnimation WindowOpacity = new DoubleAnimation()
    {
        From = Opacity,
        To = 0,
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300)
    };

    WindowOpacity.Completed += (se, ex) => { Opacity = 1; WindowState = WindowState.Minimized; };
    BeginAnimation(Window.OpacityProperty, WindowOpacity);
}
```

When the window is minimized, I cause a opacity `Opacity = 1;` (so that I can see a screenshot on the taskbar when mouseover).

Why does the assignment fail `Opacity = 1;`? The resulting opacity is set to zero. Why is this not working? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default animations keep the final value after they are completed. If you want to reset the value after they are completed, you should set `FillBehavior` to `Stop`:

```
DoubleAnimation WindowOpacity = new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            From = Opacity,
            To = 0,
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300),
            FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop
        };

        WindowOpacity.Completed += (se, ex) => { WindowState = WindowState.Minimized; };
        BeginAnimation(Window.OpacityProperty, WindowOpacity);
```

Comment: Thank. I understood.